# prevent color scheme from bleeding into terminal

Tags: colorscheme

I use a modified version of `industry` where my `normal` text color is bright white instead of grey.

Here is the offending line

```
highlight Normal ctermfg=white ctermbg=Black guifg=#dddddd  guibg=Black
```

I am having a problem in gnu screen where the bright white-ness bleeds into the next line of text in my terminal and so on until I reset it by hand with the command `printf "\033[0m"`

I tried to fix this by having vim execute the following command:

```
autocmd VimLeave * :call Printf_Fixup()

function! Printf_Fixup()
    !printf '\033[0m'
endfunction
```

but unfortunately, vim doesn't "just execute" the shell command `printf '\033[0m'` when exiting, it sometimes prompts me to manually press enter. not sure what's going on there.

Is there a way to configure vim to be more aggressive when "displaying" a colorscheme and use redundant ansi resets all over the place?

Comment: Any chance `:set t_te=^[[0m` works? (Where the ^[ is a literal escape: press Ctrl+v then esc).

Comment: @Rich that actually works perfectly in this case (although I'm not sure what it does).

Comment: I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I think it suggests though that my termcap is misconfigured in screen ... otherwise I wouldn't need to direct vim to ignore it, no?

Comment: It does suggest that, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim reads the `ti` and `te` [capabilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_chapter/termcap_4.html) from your termcap and sends the commands in these to the terminal when it starts up and exits, respectively.

You could manually override the `te` setting to instead emit your escape sequence for clearing colours with the following command:

```
:let &t_te = "\<esc>[0m"
```

This shouldn't be necessary, though: Does `:set t_te?` report different values when Vim is run within screen and when it is not? If so, you may want to inspect the value stored for `te` in your `terminfo` database by running `terminfo -C` from the shell within and outside of screen.

[See my earlier answer to a similar question for a bit more detail on the `t_te` setting.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11911/how-can-vim-be-configured-to-restore-normal-terminal-color-on-exit/11918#11918)